# WE Glock 35 TMSS stuck slide

Tags: equipment, airsoft

Please refer to the image below.

[image: 1]

I forgot to put back the black part on the picture after cleaning some internal parts. After pulling the trigger, the slide goes over the back and stays there.

How do I disassemble the slide in this position?